# How to code for Google Spreadsheet stock check email

Tags: javascript, email, google-sheets

Right now I am trying to set up a function that could help my colleague to update the stocking. I need a program that as soon as the stock update is done, an email of stock notice will be sent to manager.

I tried to run the program without trigger and I received a perfect email for stocking, but now I need to apply a trigger to the program so when my colleague update stock she does not need to run the program to send the email.

I just want to know how could I get a better way to trigger the email sending instead of every update it trigger the program running and sending multiple emails.Also please give me some idea about how to set range 'e' and how the trigger works

Thanks

here is the code

```
 function onEdit(e) {
   //if (activeSheet.getName() !== "inventory") return;
   //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var sheet = e.source;
   var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
   var numRows = rows.getNumRows(); 
   var workRows = numRows -8;
   var dataRange = sheet.getRange(8,2, workRows, 13)
   // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
   var data = dataRange.getValues();

   //email information and content
   var emailAddress = 'xxx@gmail.com';  
   var bodyrefill = '';      
   var bodyset = '';
   var bodysend = '';
   var subject = '';
   var check1 = 0;
   var check2 = 0;

  /*
   var range = e.range;
   var columnOfCellEdited = range.getColumn();
   if (columnOfCellEdited==14){

     columnofCellEdited.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());

     }
     */

   for (var row in data){
     if(data[row][12]!=0){
       if (data[row][11]<=data[row][12]){
         check1 += 1;
         var num = data[row][12]-data[row][11];
         bodyrefill = bodyrefill + "The " + row + " line, " + data[row][2] + "          needs refill product for" + num + "\n";
       }
     }
     else{
       check2 += 1;
       bodyset = bodyset + "The " + row + " line, product " + data[row][2] + " needs to set up a product limit." + "\n";
     }
   }

   if (check1 > 0){
     if (check2 > 0){
       subject = "Google sheet has products need to refill and set up alart limit.";
       bodysend = bodyrefill + bodyset;
     }
     else{
       subject = "Google sheet has products need to refill.";
       bodysend = bodyrefill;
     }
   }
   else{
     subject = "Google sheet has products need to set up alart limit.";
     bodysend = bodyset;
   }
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, bodysend);
   SpreadsheetApp.flush();

 }
```